# What do you do when your page displays incorrectly on your server, but correctly in jsFiddle?

Tags: html, css

I have a page which is displaying incorrectly in Firefox and Chrome (in that the tbodies do not show borders); however it displays correctly in jsfiddle (here: http://jsfiddle.net/JwkrD/ - both browsers).

I'm not sure how to proceed - how do I get the tbodies to show up on my page in the same way as they do in jsfiddle?

I'm using the same DOCTYPE, both pages are being served up with type text/html. I can't find any other differences.

Comment: Did you inspect the headers returned?

Comment: @Lucero Yes. I can't seen any material difference (in particular, it's the same content-type). I'm happy to receive your suggestions for other headers to look for.

Comment: You host your site on JS fiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS fiddle applies normaize.css which adds

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Adding that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's really not being added by javascript. If you don't believe me, search for it in the html box in the jsfiddle, and you'll see it in the markup. If it's not showing up when you copy it locally, that adds a whole new level of weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for this - much puzzlement has been avoided. As usual, I could *swear* I tried adding this.